# Auto generating cookies when sending post request

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I am trying to send a Http Post request to a website with these headers :

```
headers = {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "cookie": "__gpi=UID=00000625243f2b12:T=1654153135:RT=1654342443:S=ALNI_MbdFxSgua2dONohDTz9bEGks8vnoQ; __gads=ID=05dae5d77dbc463f:T=1654153135:S=ALNI_MbLIzKIHhP022gtr7bRBqu9PSxNtQ; PHPSESSID=8a932c5bbe4d667513dfdc3a0051ed37",
    "origin": "https://www.dcode.fr",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "referer": "https://www.dcode.fr/cipher-identifier",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36 OPR/87.0.4390.45",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }
```

At first it is working perfectly.
But after some time this stop working.I think because cookies expire.

Erroneous Output :

```
{"captcha":"<script>$.getScript('https:\/\/www.google.com\/recaptcha\/api.js').done(function( script, textStatus ) {\n  $('#captcha').addClass('g-recaptcha').attr({'data-sitekey':'6LeoCVQaAAAAALADLNorGItVJxP40YUjD1Q3S0zp','data-callback':'recaptcha_callback'});\n });\n<\/script>\n<div id='captcha'><\/div>"}
```

Expected output :

```
{"caption":"dCode's analyzer suggests to investigate:","results":{"<a href=\"\/rot-13-cipher\" target=\"_blank\">ROT-13 Cipher<\/a>":"\u25a0\u25a0","<a href=\"\/base-58-cipher\" target=\"_blank\">Base 58<\/a>":"\u25a0","<a href=\"\/playfair-cipher\" target=\"_blank\">PlayFair Cipher<\/a>":"\u25a0","<a href=\"\/base-64-encoding\" target=\"_blank\">Base64 Coding<\/a>":"\u25a0","<a href=\"\/substitution-cipher\" target=\"_blank\">Substitution Cipher<\/a>":"\u25aa","<a href=\"\/rot-cipher\" target=\"_blank\">ROT Cipher<\/a>":"\u25aa","<a href=\"\/caesar-cipher\" target=\"_blank\">Caesar Cipher<\/a>":"\u25aa","<a href=\"\/shift-cipher\" target=\"_blank\">Shift Cipher<\/a>":"\u25aa","<a href=\"\/hill-cipher\" target=\"_blank\">Hill Cipher<\/a>":"\u25aa","<a href=\"\/affine-cipher\" target=\"_blank\">Affine Cipher<\/a>":"\u25aa","<a href=\"\/keyboard-change-cipher\" target=\"_blank\">Keyboard Change Cipher<\/a>":"\u25ab","<a href=\"\/vigenere-cipher\" target=\"_blank\">Vigenere Cipher<\/a>":"\u25ab","<a href=\"\/homophonic-cipher\" target=\"_blank\">Homophonic Cipher<\/a>":"\u25ab","<a href=\"\/autoclave-cipher\" target=\"_blank\">Autoclave Cipher<\/a>":"\u25ab","<a href=\"\/beaufort-cipher\" target=\"_blank\">Beaufort Cipher<\/a>":"\u25ab","<a href=\"\/burrows-wheeler-transform\" target=\"_blank\">Burrows\u2013Wheeler Transform<\/a>":"\u25ab"}
```

### If I copy the cookie from capturing requests using browser's developer tools and paste it in code, Then it will work again for a short amount of time.

How can I byoass this recaptcha error ?

Comment: I don't think it is happening because of cookies expired but that website detected that you are using bot and sending captcha. Learn more about reCAPTCHA from [here](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/)

Comment: How can I stop letting that website detect that I am a bot. When I add new cookie after getting it using browser developer tools, it works. How can I generate cookies like the browser does ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the website or api is running some kind of js authentication to block anything that is not a browser to bypass this you have 2 options

either reverse the js and understand how the cookies are constructed and replicate them in python (this is very hard and might take weeks of reverse engineering)

or you can create a selenium instance that visits the site and waits for the cookies to be present then simply passes them to requests you will have to do this each time captcha is presented (this is the easier option but this will make your script slower)

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily because cookies are expired, take a look at your output, it's a recaptcha. You need to solve the captcha first.

In addition to that, make sure you are changing requests' default useragent.
Consider using `requests.Session` if you are not using it already or alternatively `selenium` if possible

Comment: I am using random useragents. Any other way to avoid the captcha ?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to completely avoid the captcha, it might be there by default. Try to use selenium if you can, and if not, you can combine both requests & selenium (for solving the captcha only) but that might be complicated.